# Javascript Error : Failed To load resource : the server responded with a status of 404()

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to change the image by hovering the mouse over the image through the javascript functions. It was working properly fine till yet. But lately when I hover the mouse over the image, the main image disappears that means the javascript code doesn't work somehow. I have debugged it on the browser and got to know about the error which I have mentioned above. I have tried to change the path of the image inside javascript and also tried to change the path of the javascript file. But it doesn't work for me.
P.S. - I am working on an ASP.Net core mvc website So my javascript file is bound with the layout page.

Here is the code of the javascript functions which I use :

```
function SwitchOn() {
    pic = "../images/switchon.png";
    document.getElementById('headImg').src = pic;
}

function SwitchOff() {
    pic = "../images/logo.png";
    document.getElementById('headImg').src = pic;
}
```

These both functions exist in webvalidations.js file which is bound with the layout page.
[image]

This is how the image disappears and error looks like when I hover the mouse over it :
[image]

This is the way I use both the functions via event in the img tag :

```
<img src="~/images/logo.png" id="headImg" onmouseover="SwitchOn()" onmouseout="SwitchOff()" style="height:100px;width:100px;" />
```

P.S. Image only disappears when I hover over it.

Comment: Is there a difference between the `~/` path and the `../` path? Also, I have never seen `~/` being used on a live site. I think you might be using file system resources here, which will break when you put this site online...

Comment: @somethinghere The `~/` prefix is an ASP.NET utility for specifying an app-relative path.

Comment: @RichardDeeming You learn something new every day! However, could that mean that the `../` path is incorrect and it should also be `~/`?

Comment: @somethinghere The `~/` prefix only works in ASP.NET views; static files like Javascript can't use it.

Comment: yeah @RichardDeeming is right. it only works with views not with javascript files. and previously it was working fine. I dunno what's wrong with it now :(

Comment: According to the description, everything worked fine before but it doesn't work now. So I think we should focus on what changed or updated recently? Add a new page? Change the folder of storing images? Or some other things.

Comment: @TinyWang yeah.. some pages has been added.. but it was working fine with all the pages. Folder structure and storage location is intact from the starting of the project.

Comment: @AzharQureshi Thanks for your reply sir. Did you try to remove the newly added pages and try again to test if the newly added pages lead to the issue? I know this idea looks stupid but I think it deserves to try.